# post-hoc (Tukey) on adonis (permanova)

Tags: r, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test, vegan

I have a bray-curtis distance matrix and found significant associations on a grouping variable with adonis (permanova) using R package vegan. Now I would like to perfrom a post-hoc test to test between groups using Tukey with [agricolae](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agricolae/agricolae.pdf).

However, the function [works only with aov and lm class objects](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/agricolae/versions/1.3-3/topics/HSD.test), while adonis is of another class:

> class (permanova_species_staging)
>
> "adonis"

Is there a possibility to coerce it to run with Tukey test of agricoale?

Or is there another possibility of pairwise comparison post-hoc test?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have a look at the [`pairwiseAdonis`](https://github.com/pmartinezarbizu/pairwiseAdonis) package, which I think does what you want. Note that questions primarily about programming are off-topic on this site.