# Repeated measures microbiome data with baseline measurement: comparison of two treatments

Tags: repeated-measures, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, permanova

I am interested in any advice I can get on different ways I might analyze multivariate ecological community (fecal sample microbiome) data that come from a "before after control impact" design as follows:

- Subjects divided into four groups. Fecal sample taken at **time 0** before any treatments are started, and the microbiomes of the fecal samples are measured.
- Starting at time 0, two of the groups are given a control diet and two are given a treatment diet for a certain length of time. At **time 1** another fecal sample is taken and microbiome measured.
- Starting at time 1, one of the control diet groups and one of the treatment diet groups is subjected to a challenge. At **time 2** another fecal sample is taken and microbiome measured.

So overall we have diet * challenge * time point interactions, with 3 repeated measures within each subject. I would like to get some ideas for possible ways to:

1. make statistical inference about whether the microbiome composition is significantly affected by the interaction of diet and challenge at time 2, accounting for the measurements at time 0 and 1.
2. descriptive or inferential analysis looking at what taxa are most associated with the different treatments on each day.

My initial thought is to do a PERMANOVA, with permutations stratified by individual, to assess whether there is a significant diet x challenge x time interaction. It would be nice to be able to do some sort of post-hoc test (see [post-hoc (Tukey) on adonis (permanova)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508857/post-hoc-tukey-on-adonis-permanova)) to do treatment comparisons at each time point within this model, but I am not sure how to do that. Following that, I was going to do a sPLS-DA analysis separately for each time point to illustrate how the treatments diverge over time. But I am interested in getting ideas on how to go about analyzing these data.

Comment: A good place to start might be to come up a model for the outcome variable. (I'm not 100% clear what the outcome variable is.) The predictors are the group assignment, the baseline measurement and the *two* time experimental points (time 1 and time 2) as well as an interaction between group and time. It will also be necessary to add random effects to account for the multiple measurements from the same subject.

Comment: Such a model would be (relatively?) easy to set up for one taxon & much harder to do for multiple taxa at the same time.

Comment: @dipetkov Yes, I agree, and I did end up setting up just such a model for each taxon separately, as part of the analysis, then did FDR corrections on the p-values. I also did the PLS discriminant analysis for the separate time points. The PERMANOVA did not really work out.

Comment: If you feel up to it, you can answer (& accept) your question with a bit more information about the analysis that worked. I'll be interested in reading about it.